# Keep Angular 2 Router from Mistaking Literals for Params

Tags: javascript, angular, router

I have two routes:

```
{
path: 'application/:groupId/:approved/:applicant-id',
component: FooComponent  
}, 
{
path: 'application/:groupId/applicant-detail/:applicant-id',
component: BarComponent  
},
```

The difference is that in the first one `:approved` is a param and in the second `applicant-detail` is a literal. Of course, the router thinks that:

`this.router.navigate(['./applicant-detail/' + this.someId, { relativeTo: this.route });`

wants to go to the first route, because it doesn't realize that `applicant-detail` is a literal. Is there any way to get around this besides re-writing routes so they don't match in 'signature'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swap the position, make the parameter one to the next and everything will work

```
{
path: 'application/:groupId/applicant-detail/:applicant-id',
component: BarComponent  
},
{
path: 'application/:groupId/:approved/:applicant-id',
component: FooComponent  
}
```

Comment: Alright, thanks, I will try it now. Can you explain why in a little more detail please?

Comment: it try to search from top to bottom, and use "application-detail" as a parameter value and use the first route rather than to go further.

Answer (score 1):

The order of your router config matters.

Swap your declarations such that your most literal paths are first.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why please? Or perhaps link in the docs.

Comment: It stores your registered paths in the order they are defined. The router takes the client-defined-path (the request) and sequentially does a comparison with your registered paths. The first match it finds is what the router returns; in this case, your component.

See docs: https://angular.io/guide/router#example-config
`The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design...`